# Normalization or standardization in stock prediction

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, normalization, standardization

Currently I watched the videos (links below) that argues using the normalization (max-min scale) is the bad idea when it comes to the stock prediction. In the videos, the editor aruges that people should use stadardization instead of normalization, becasue in the prediction, you never know the "highest" price and "lowest" price in the future. Therefore,it makes normalization be no sense becuase it will transform the data from 0 to 1 which constrain the model to in this range.

But I found out that in most of papers (includes my own), we use normalization and it just works fine to predict the future. But I am a bit confused now, with his logic, won't all the price or no bound trend prediction has to use standardization? So which should technique should we use? Normalization or standardization?

Video links:
https://youtu.be/Vfx1L2jh2Ng

Comment: It's hard to make sense of this because, by the same token, it is almost surely to happen that when applying standardization, the new data will not have mean 0 and standard deviation 1 after applying the transformation ... It's been my experience that YouTube videos are not a great resource for  useful machine learning content.

Comment: It's a legitimate question, but I think the issue is predicated on a false assumption: namely, that re-expressing the (response) variable to fall within a 0 to 1 range constrains the *predictions* to that range.  Although that's true of some models, (1) the same models will not cope with standardized values at all and (2) in all other cases there is a simple linear relationship between the standardized and normalized values, involving relatively tiny changes of location and scale, which means it really shouldn't matter which method you use. Thus, *the answer depends on the model.*

Comment: Thank you guys! I think I understand it now. I forgot to mention the MinMaxScaler that I used is sci-kit learn's. The idea of sci-kit learn's MinMaxScaler is that even if the test data is out of range of the fit one. It can transform the data into the larger scale to prevent the error. For example, if your scaler set as [0, 1] where the max value in training data is 20. If the test data has 40, then the tranform data will be larger than 1, perhaps 2. So the "constraining the prediction" assumption is not exising. I have proven within my own LSTM model.